# GetClientCert is not picking up on IIS hosted api

Tags: c#, iis-7, ssl-certificate, client-certificates, x509certificate2

I tried to validate cert manually on WEB API. Issue is all time, `GetClientCertificate` just returns null.

```
            var certRequest= actionContext.Request.GetClientCertificate();
            certRequest == null ? "Certificate not found" : $"Certificate found";
```

IIS web site is like, https://testapi.web.com
cert file that attached on SSL is appear as DNS=*.web.com .
there is another cert file its on cert store and but, not mapped along with HTTPS binding.
that DNS =cl-testapi.web.com

I tried to supply both the cert file from client call and each time, `GetClientCertificate` file received as null.

```
client side code:

var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
                {
                    SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls | SslProtocols.Ssl3 | SslProtocols.Ssl2
                };
                handler.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2(@"c:\testcert.cer"));
                
                var client = new HttpClient(handler);
                
                var data = new StringContent([xmlcontent], Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");
                var result = client.PostAsync("https://testapi.web.com", data).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                var resultString = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Can any one suggest what is wrong on this.

verified, IIS has, "accept" as SSL setting. Also, both the cert files are valid and neighter is able to pick on server api while using 'GetClientCert'.

///////////
Tried with cert file to search on client cert store and attach,

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
                {
                    SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls | SslProtocols.Ssl3 | SslProtocols.Ssl2
                };
                X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
                store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
                var certCollection = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "thumbprintGUID COPIED FROM CLIENT CERT", false);
                handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certCollection[0]);
                var client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

//notes, `certCollection[0].HasPrivateKey` is `false` here.

Update:
Now requesting using, PFX file and password. I can see, Private key exists is true.
`certCollection[0].HasPrivateKey` is `true` here. But, GetClientCert is not received.

Comment: your certificate doesn't have private key. It won't work this way.

Comment: Its a client cert file. Its exported from mmc console.

Comment: the certificate is not associated with private key, so client certificate cannot perform authentication and IIS will reject it (not sure if it will be ever sent to IIS). You need a certificate with associated private key.

Comment: Now, exported cert file from server with private key and installed on local cert store through pfx file. Now, attached cert file using `X509Store` and search cert by thumbprint. I can see, cert file is able to find and attached on `handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certcollection[0])`;  but its still server says, GetClientCert is null

Comment: show your new code. And does `cert.HasPrivateKey` property return True?

Comment: Edited question that just tried.

Comment: @Crypt32 still `HasPrivateKey` return `false` . how it can be included? Cert is exported with privatekey and installed on client store.

Comment: @Crypt32 now able to pass PrivateKey using pfx file and it says, `HasPrivateKey` `true`. thing is, its getting another issue like, `A fatal error occurred while creating a TLS client credential. The internal error state is 10013` , its matching for TLS version server as well as httpclient TLS12.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to correct the permissions on the c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys folder to solve the 10013 error.

1. Everyone Access: Special Applies to: This folder only
2. Network Service Access: Read & Execute Applies to: This folder, subfolders and files
3. Administrators Access: Full Control Applies to: This folder, subfolder and files
4. System Access: Full control Applies to: This folder, subfolder and files
5. IUSR Access: Full Control Applies to: This folder, subfolder and files

Comment: I have set the permission on cert file under the Cert Store. Permission for application pool. Also tried with `Everyone` permission but same issue as of now.

Comment: That may be a .Net Framework problem, you can try make registry change.  This is the link of a similar error with the issue: [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fd626e47-9ee7-41c5-b11a-ae696e3b6b5b/a-fatal-error-occurred-while-creating-a-tls-client-credential-the-internal-error-state-is-10013?forum=ws2016).