# C# How to authenticate certificate once loaded into x509certificate2 object

Tags: c#, api, rest, authentication, x509

I have created a program which uses a REST API to retrieve information from a local server.  If I turn off certificate authentication it works.

I have learned how to load an x509Certificate2 object from a .pem file but I'm not sure what to do with it.

Currently the program dies at the following line:

```
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
```

with the error:  Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

Any insight would be helpful.

```
        public string makeRequest()
        {
            //-----------------------------------------------------------
            X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2("cacert.pem");
            Console.WriteLine("Certificate Loaded From File");
            byte[] rawdata = cert.RawData;
            Console.WriteLine("==> Public Key: {0}", cert.PublicKey.Key.ToXmlString(false));

            string strResponseValue = string.Empty;

            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(endPoint);
            request.Method = httpMethod.ToString();
            request.ContentType = "application/vnd.netbackup+json;version=1.0";

            //-----------------------------------------------------------
            // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
            string postData = "{ \"userName\":\"root\", \"password\":\"somepass\" }";
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

            // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            // Get the request stream.
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
```

Comment: you have same problem as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64358962/getclientcert-is-not-picking-up-on-iis-hosted-api (see comments under OP question). Your PEM file doesn't contain private key.

Comment: I can use the .pem file with both curl and python (see below) without a private key and it avoids the authentication errors.  I am just trying to validate that the server.

Comment: @Crypt32 I can use the .pem file with both curl and python (see below) without a private key and it avoids the authentication errors.  I am just trying to validate the server.  - curl --cacert <cacert.pem>  - Python Requests: requests.get/post(..., verify='/path/to/cacert.pem')

Comment: Can you elaborate what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Crypt32 - Yes, I am currently turning off server authentication in my C# program which I understand is bad.  If I call the same API using curl I can authenticate the server with just the .pem file by adding the "--cacert certfile.pem" argument.  If I call the same API using Python's requests module, I can authenticate the server with just the .pem file by using requests.get(..., verify='/path/to/certfile.pem').  I don't use a key with curl or python.  I would like to emulate this functionality with C#.